# How to check if CoreData is empty?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4, xcdatamodel

I am trying to check if certain entity has data, so I wrote this code I am not sure if my code correct.When I check my code I found that if there is a data I got the answer that "data exist", but if there is no data compiler ignore else statement. I cannot understand why this happen.

```
   func entityIsEmpty()
   {
     let context = objAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>.init(entityName: "myEntity")

     //do{
     //result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
     result = fetchRequest as! [NSManagedObject] //ERROR
     for data in result{

     var obj = userNSObj()
     obj.myObject = data.value(forKey: "myAttribute") as! String


     myArray.append(obj)
        if myArray != nil{
            print("data exist")
        }else{
            print("data not exist")
        }
                        }

             //}catch{
             //print("Failed")
            //}

   }
```

Comment: Replace `if myArray != nil` with `if !myArray.isEmpty`. However this works reliably only if the array is empty at the beginning of the method.

Comment: It take me directly to ```catch```

Comment: Just changing the line cannot `throw` an error.

Comment: Please see updated question. I am not sure about the change I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit you messed up the code.

This checks if the fetched data array is empty and `return`s if the array is empty

```
func entityIsEmpty()
{
    let context = objAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<myEntity>(entityName: "myEntity")

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if result.isEmpty {
            print("data not exist")
            return
        } else {
            print("data exist")
        }

        for data in result {
            var obj = userNSObj()
            obj.myObject = data.myAttribute
            myArray.append(obj)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```